# Swift / How to use extensions

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have tried to declare an extension for a class, but I'm receiving erros. What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says. Extensions aren't allowed to store properties. Just declare `var somePoint = (1, 1)` in the main Class. Not within the Extension.

You have stored it like this

```
extension AFErorr...... {
   var somePoint = (1, 1)
}
```

But you need to put it inside the Class itself.

```
class AFErorr...... {
   var somePoint = (1, 1)
}
```

Switch somePoint is declared outside of the Class. That is the 2nd error. You need to declare it within the Class. And then the 3rd error should be gone as well.

```
class AFErorr...... {
   switch somePoint.... {
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't have a class set up. It's just an extension that came automatic when I downloaded Alamofire. Do I need to create a new class?

Comment: no. next to `extension` there is already the Class that is exceeded by the extension. just hit [CMD] and click on that name, then you'll land in the class. remove your code in there

Comment: A "?" pops up whenever I try to click on it :(

Comment: Then just scroll up to the end of this page. It's very likely that the Extension you're currently creating your code at is part of the same .swift file...

Comment: @DeborahElizabethPadilla I can't help you if you're not talking to me :)

Comment: Sorry! Was trying to figure it out :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125745/discussion-between-deborah-elizabeth-padilla-and-david-seek).